# javascript jquery checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a piece of JavaScript. I'm completely new to JS, But I have a group of checkboxes part of the domainchkb class and with the name, all with different values. I am trying to group those into an array to format into JSON. When executing the code the debugger stops at `return this.parent().text();`. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function format4Cart(){
    var domains;

    var values = $('input[name=domainchkb]:checked').map(function(){
            return this.parent().text();
    }).get();

    domains = "{\"type\" : \"single\", \"data\" : [";

    $.each(values, function(domainIndex,selected_domain){
            domains += "{\"id\" : \""+selected_domain+"\", \"domain\" : \""+whois_response.data.domain+"\"},";
    });
    $(domains).text().replace(/(\s+)?.$/,"");
    domains += "]}";
    domains=encodeURIComponent(domains);
    ajaxAdd2Cart(domains);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a jQuery method, `.parent()`, on a DOM element.  In order to use a jQuery method on the element, you need to wrap it in a jQuery call:

```
var values = $('input[name=domainchkb]:checked').map(function(){ 
        return $(this).parent().text(); 
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you Gilly and everyone else for their help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the debugger already just look at it see what values are there for `this` and other variables. Might be something you do not expect. I think the issue is that you're trying to use `this` while you should use function parameter:

```
var values = $('input[name=domainchkb]:checked').map(function(checkbox){
        return checkbox.parent().text();
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now. Basicly I'm checking if a domain is registered and if not allowing the person to select a group of them and then send it to a script to generate products and add them to a magento cart for check out. Then link them to a reseller API once a IPN has been received purchase the domains from reseller and send the information to them in a email.

Comment: It still exits the routine after the first pass just like before. hmm.